Multi module build error :domain:main: Could not resolve project :data
I have a simple multi module structure

app module

presentation module (Android library Module)

domain module (Kotlin library Module)

data module (Android library Module)


The dependency graph I want to achieve is: presentation -> domain -> data
Inside the Presentation build.gradle:
implementation(projects.domain)

Inside the Domain build.gradle:
implementation(projects.data)

And I keep getting these gradle sync error:
:domain:main: Could not resolve project :data.
Required by:
    project :domain

Possible solution:
 - Declare repository providing the artifact, see the documentation at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html

and this
:domain:test: Could not resolve project :data.
Required by:
    project :domain

Possible solution:
 - Declare repository providing the artifact, see the documentation at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html

If I remove this implementation(projects.data) line from the build.gradle it build but I want to have a dependency on the data module
Longer error:
* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':domain:compileJava'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':domain:compileClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve project :data.
     Required by:
         project :domain
      > No matching variant of project :data was found. The consumer was configured to find a library for use during compile-time, compatible with Java 8, preferably in the form of class files, preferably optimized for standard JVMs, and its dependencies declared externally, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'jvm' but:
          - Variant 'debugApiElements' declares a library for use during compile-time, preferably optimized for Android:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'androidJvm' and the consumer needed a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'jvm'
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about how its dependencies are found (required its dependencies declared externally)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them preferably in the form of class files)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8)
          - Variant 'debugRuntimeElements' declares a library for use during runtime, preferably optimized for Android:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'androidJvm' and the consumer needed a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'jvm'
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about how its dependencies are found (required its dependencies declared externally)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them preferably in the form of class files)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8)
          - Variant 'debugSourcesElements' declares a component for use during runtime, packaged as a jar, preferably optimized for Android, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares documentation, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'androidJvm' and the consumer needed a library, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'jvm'
              - Other compatible attribute:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8)
          - Variant 'releaseApiElements' declares a library for use during compile-time, preferably optimized for Android:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'androidJvm' and the consumer needed a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'jvm'
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about how its dependencies are found (required its dependencies declared externally)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them preferably in the form of class files)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8)
          - Variant 'releaseRuntimeElements' declares a library for use during runtime, preferably optimized for Android:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'androidJvm' and the consumer needed a component, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'jvm'
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about how its dependencies are found (required its dependencies declared externally)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them preferably in the form of class files)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8)
          - Variant 'releaseSourcesElements' declares a component for use during runtime, packaged as a jar, preferably optimized for Android, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares documentation, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'androidJvm' and the consumer needed a library, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'jvm'
              - Other compatible attribute:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8)


Try implementation(project(":domain")) syntax for establishing dependencies between modules. The syntax you are trying to use is called a type-safe project accessors, and it's not enabled unless by default, unless you explicitly state: enableFeaturePreview("TYPESAFE_PROJECT_ACCESSORS")
